# Export scoped var from custom JSP tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, var

In the JSTL `fmt` tag library is the tag `formatDate`, which has an optional attribute `var`. When using the `formatDate` tag, you can pass in a string via the `var` attribute that specifies the name of the variable that will be created, whose value will be the formatted date string.

Unfortunately, Java (as of Java 8) doesn't support the Tongan and Samoan locales, which I need. Therefore, a co-worker created a custom date formatting tag that basically just formats the date using `fmt:formatDate` but then (in the case of Tongan and Samoan) replaces the day name and month name values with the appropriate translations. However, this custom tag only outputs (using `c:out`) the result, and I'd like to enhance the custom tag to be able to create a variable, just like `fmt:formatDate` does. Unfortunately, I don't know how.

`c:set` doesn't allow expressions in its `var` attribute, and for some reason `pageContext` is null inside the custom tag file (date-formatter.tag).

So here's what I have for the tag definition, minus extraneous details (assume the `c` and `fmt` taglibs are included, as well as the `dateFormatterLocale` variable):

```
<%@attribute name="value" type="java.util.Date" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="..." @>
<%@attribute name="type" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="..." %>
<%@attribute name="pattern" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="..." %>
<%@attribute name="var" required="false" rtexprvalue="false" description="..." %>

<fmt:formatDate type="${type}" pattern="${pattern}" value="${value}" var="dfFormattedDate" />
<c:if test="${((dateFormatterLocale == 'to') || (dateFormatterLocale == 'sm'))}">
    ...
    [stuff to translate day names and month names]
    ...
</c:if>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty var}">
        <%-- SOMEHOW SET VARIABLE WHOSE NAME IS THE VALUE OF "var" AND WHOSE VALUE IS THE VALUE OF dfFormattedDate --%>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:out value="${dfFormattedDate}" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<c:set>` with a `target` on the desired scope map and `property` on the `${var}`.

E.g. if you need it to be request scoped:

```
<c:set target="${requestScope}" property="${var}" value="${dfFormattedDate}" />
```

Or page scoped:

```
<c:set target="${pageScope}" property="${var}" value="${dfFormattedDate}" />
```